# A mysterious downvote and comments are missing

Tags: discussion, specific-question, deleted-comments, downvoted-questions

Today I noticed that two of my questions were downvoted (the other day another one was, but that downvote has vanished). The other downvoted question doesn't matter, it was self-answered, not everyone's taste, no reason for a downvote but who cares.

- [Tables and breaking columns onto a new page in MigraDoc](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4396423/tables-and-breaking-columns-onto-a-new-page-in-migradoc)

But I can't explain the downvote on that one. And more importantly, there were comments to that question (from another user and myself) which are now gone. Yes, it was a simple "me too!" comment, but since when do they get removed? Was there a flag issued on the question and that's why the comments are gone? Am I paranoid?

**Edit:** Yes I know it's a vague question, but my main concerns are the vanished comments, and if they have something to do with the downvote, or if they are unassociated.

Comment: I would suspect that they are unrelated. A moderator will have cleaned up the comments.

Comment: The mysterious downvotes seem to be multiplying on this very question. Where could they come from???

Comment: As Chris mentioned, moderators have the ability to wipe out all the comments with a single click. And they also (now) have the ability to see all of the deleted comments. But it's unlikely that deleted comments have anything to do with downvotes, unless you're hoping that one of the comments *explained* the downvote? That's asking for a lot. :-)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There was an answer to the question with comments, but that answer -- which really wasn't -- was deleted by a moderator.  10K+ users can still see the deleted answer and comments.  Not sure why the answer wasn't converted to a comment other than it wasn't particularly helpful to point out that he was having the same problem.

I can't answer why someone downvoted it.

Comment: It was an answer, not a comment? In that case I apologize for my leaky memory...I wouldn't have asked I would have remembered that.

Comment: 10k users can see deleted posts, but not deleted comments; at least that is what happens on SE 2.0 sites.

Comment: @kia: 10k can see comments (that haven't been deleted) on deleted posts; other users cannot see them.

Comment: @Rick Sladkey I just wanted to precisate, in the case somebody read it as "10K+ users can still see the deleted answer and [deleted] comments." If users deleted their comments before the answer is deleted, then only moderators can see the deleted comment, who are the only one to see deleted comments on not deleted posts.